# reference configmap to template deployment

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm developing helm parent and sub charts but have difficulty sharing particular (unique) hash values.

I have a parent chart `P`, and two sub charts: one configs chart `C` and one worker chart `W`. For simplicity, here assume `C` only contain one configmap, `W` only contain one deployment. When deploy `P`, `C` and `W` are deployed automatically, just working as expected.

Now think of we need generate one unique string value `id` (hash in particular) in `C`, based on the actual config files' contents.

```yaml
id: {{ $.Files.Get "some config files in chart" | sha256sum }}
```

`id` will later be used by other components not mentioned here at runtime, so moving the value out of `C` is not an option.

Now the **goal** is set the same unique `id` as some part of deployment in `W`, particularlly, as `volumeMounts.subPath`.

Have tried following deployment syntax to include the configmap value as environement variable, then set as `subPath`. Some unrelated yaml sections omitted.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: SUBPATH
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: THEKEY
              name: theconfigmap
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - args ["-c", "echo $(SUBPATH)"]
        image: thedockerimagename
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /somepath
          name: volumnname
          subPath: $(SUBPATH)
```

But seems environement variable only work for the process in container (`echo $(SUBPATH)` can show the `id`), not work for templating the deployment yaml(of course this is reasonable, but I'm seeking some ways to accomplish).

Also tried `subPath: ${SUBPATH}`, neither not work.
Even thought of ways such as in `P` package pipeline, use some scripts to pull `C` down and extract the `id` and replace it into `W`. but prefer if there exists more elegant built in mechanism.

Comment: In order to avoid dulication, consider utilizing the global key which you can control from the outermost parent. https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#global-chart-values